# If $W\subset X$ is an open set, is $f^{-1}(Y-f(X-W))\subset W$ for any closed map $f:X\to Y$?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, functions

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a closed map. My book "Topology and Geometry" by Bredon says $f^{-1}(Y-f(X-W))\subset W$, where $W\subset X$ is an open set.

1. Shouldn't $f$ be declared to be surjective for $f^{-1}(Y-f(X-W))$ to be defined?
2. If $f$ is indeed surjective, shouldn't $f^{-1}(Y-f(X-W))=W$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$f^{-1}$ is not a function, it is merely notation : For any set $V \subset Y$, we write
$$
f^{-1}(V) = \{x \in X : f(x) \in V\}
$$

Comment: Thank you. That answers my first question. As for the second question?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question, let $f:\Bbb R\to\{y\}$ be a map. This is surjective, but for $W=(0,\infty)$ we get $Y-f(X-(0,\infty))=Y-f((-\infty,0])=Y-\{y\}=\emptyset,$ so $f^{-1}(Y-f(X-W))=\emptyset\ne W$.

Note that $f^{-1}(Y-f(X-W))$ can be written as $X-f^{-1}(f(X-W))$, and since $f^{-1}(f(A))=A$ for each $A\subseteq X$ if and anly if $f$ is injective, the statement $$f^{-1}(Y-f(X-W))=W\ \text{ for all } W\subseteq X$$ is equivalent to $f$ being injective.

Comment: If $f$ is not injective, is $f^{-1}(f(A))\supset A$ for $A\subset X$?

Comment: @AyushKhaitan: Yes, for some $A\subset X$

Comment: @StefanH- Isn't this true for all mappings, rather than just being true for closed mappings?

Comment: @AyushKhaitan: For all set maps we have $A\subseteq f^{-1}(f(A))$, and $A= f^{-1}(f(A))$ for all $A\subseteq X$ iff $f$ is injective.

Answer (score 1):

This is a well-known lemma for closed maps, and the fact that is proved is: let $f: X \to Y$ be a closed map. Let $y \in Y$ and let $W \subset X$ be open such that $F_y = f^{-1}[\{y\}] \subset W$ ($W$ is an open neighbourhood of the so-called *fibre* $F_y$ of $y$). Then there is an open neighbourhood $O$ of $y$ such that $f^{-1}[O] \subset W$.

Here as usual, for any function $f: X \to Y$, $f^{-1}[A] = \{x \in X: f(x) \in A\}$, for any subset $A \subset Y$.

The proof goes by noting that $O = Y - f[X - W]$ is indeed open (as $f$ is a closed map and $X - W$ is closed in $X$, $W$ being open), and is a neighbourhood of $y$: suppose not, then $y \in f[X - W]$ and so there is some $p \in X - W$ with $f(p) = y$. This $p$ is in $F_y$ by definition (it maps to $y$...) and so in $W$ (which contains $F_y$), contradicting $p \in X - W$.

So the remaining thing to show is $f^{-1}[O] \subset W$, which is the subject of your question. Let $p \in f^{-1}[O]$, so $f(p) \in O$. Suppose (for a contradiction) that $p \notin W$, so $p \in X - W$; then $f(p) \in f[X - W]$ and so $f(p) \notin O$ (as $O$ is the complement of $f[X - W]$), and this is a contradiction: $f(p)$ cannot both be in $O$ and $Y - O$. So indeed $f^{-1}[O] \subset W$ as claimed, end of proof.

Comment: This is even equivalent to closedness.